# glossaries \leftmark and \rightmark not translated

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, glossaries, babel

I was trying to make an article in french with a glossary (glossaire in our weird tongue), and I noticed that, even if I did manage to set the translation right for the body, the \leftmark (or \rightmark) used by fancyhdr is still in english.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[acronym,xindy,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
    \addto{\captionsfrancais}{
      \renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Glossaire}
    }

\newglossaryentry{thingy}
{
  name=thingy,
  description={something}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\sc\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\sc\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\gls{thingy}

\newpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: translationproblem]

Any idea how to get the correct translation in the header too?

Edit: and if I want a different translation altogether ("termes techniques", for example)?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using `\captionsfrench` and not `\captionsfrancais`, but the right word is already set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `glossaries` package uses `translator`, but this package seems not to be aware of the current language and the language to be used must be passed to it.

So you need either to set the language option in `\documentclass` or load the `translator` package with the correct option.

In the two codes below I mention only the relevant packages.

### Choice 1

```
\documentclass[francais]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[acronym,xindy,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
```

### Choice 2

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[francais]{translator}
\usepackage[acronym,xindy,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
```

[image]

---

Note: the fixed words for French (at least those that are not managed by `translator` in this case) should be modified with

```
\addto\captionsfrench
```

and not with `\addto\captionsfrancais`.

---

If you want to change the generic title for glossaries, say for using *Termes* instead of *Glossaire*, the `translator` facility is needed:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewtranslation[to=French]{Glossary}{Termes}%
}
```

(sorry for the clumsiness of this approach, but it's not my fault).

Alternatively, if you have a single glossary, use the `title` option and type

```
\printglossary[title=Termes]
```

instead of `\printglossaries`.

Comment: That works. Thanks for the tip, since \renewcommand is not even needed anymore. But if I may be a little more demanding, the header word is the translation of glossary in french. If I want to change the name of the glossary (to something like "termes" for examples), how do I get to have "termes" in the header too?

Comment: @user37673 I added some directions.

Comment: Hum. the second solution works, but I need acronyms too (which I use to introduce translated terms, hence my question --- I need to "translate" acronyms by "Termes traduits"). For the first solution, though, I get a `translation of ``Glossary'' not defined` Error, though (which is quite weird, since it _is_ translated just fine). If I switch to `\newtranslation[to=French]{Glossary}{Termes}`, the message goes away (duh!), but the translation doesn't work.

Comment: @user37673 `\renewtranslation[to=French]{Acronyms}{Termes traduits}` in the same place as the other one should do.

Comment: Ok, that works... Apparently I can't use `\AtBeginDocument`. And in my case, the translation is not defined, so I need to write `\newtranslation[to=French]{Acronyms}{Termes traduits}` (and not `\renewtranslation`), after my `\begin{document}`. I guess that'll do. (Though I'll have to understand why `\AtBeginDocument` doesn't work.) Thanks!